# Чем заменить в эпоху HTML5 удобный в прошлом тег <br>? (пример на Fiddle)

Tags: html, css

пример:

```html
<span style="font:bold 24px 'verdana'; color:#2275c2;">Как перенести вторую строку на новую строку?</span>  
<span style="font:bold 18px 'verdana'; color:#666666;">(Вот эту серую строку, как?)</span>
```

Раскопал вот такой параметр CSS - `white-space: pre;`, он и есть самый верный и правильный заменитель `<br>`?
А то увидел здесь на проекте, что нужно создавать пустые div'ы или же пустые абзацы `<p>`. Лично я думаю, что создание "затычек", не есть хорошо.
И так `white-space: pre;` самый правильный заменитель `<br>`? Или есть вариант более правильный и подходящий?

---

**UPD! Почитал спецификацию HTML5, оказывается тег `<br>` не устарел, а устарел всего лишь его атрибут `clear`**

Вопрос закрыт!

Comment: а зачем его вообще заменять?

Comment: Тег `<br />` никуда не делся, а `white-space: pre` является CSS версией тега `<pre></pre>` с некоторыми отличиями. А вариантов переноса много, каждый использует тот, который удобнее/больше нравится/семантически правильный. Поэтому это не "затычки", а особенности верстки.

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо большое за наведение на почитать спецификацию HTML5. Он оказывается не устарел, а устарел лишь его атребут `clear`.